# Order by orders only by days not months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey i can't seem to be able to solve this, i have this query :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch  
FROM Calls 
ORDER BY Batch
```

Which orders the columns by days and not as regular date, meaning i get something like :

```
1.11.12
1.12.12
2.11.12
3.11.12
4.11.12
```

How am i able to solve this?
if i try and order by time, the query won't distinct the values and messes up my all query.

Meaning this :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch , time 
FROM Calls 
ORDER BY time, Batch
```

Orders the query fine but won't distinct the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch
FROM Calls 
ORDER BY time, Batch
```

**update:**

```
select convert(varchar(8), time, 4) as [Batch]
from [Calls]
group by convert(varchar(8), time, 4)
order by convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), time, 4), 4)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe7ef/1)

Comment: Tried that , error : `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: SQL Server, i'm sorry my mistake.